# Google Merchant - XML attribute characters are invalid

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I am trying to import XML file with products to Google Merchant account and it shows error that there is problems with description attribute - some of the characters in your items seem to be invalid.

In PHP code description is printed out like this:

```
htmlspecialchars($product['description'], ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')
```

From 10 000 products 200 products have error with description. One of the descriptions that have error:

> Denne klassiker forudså nutidens voldsepidemi i skolerne. rgang ´84 følger den flinke musiklærer Andy Norris (Perry King), som begår den fejl at gå imod eleverne på den berygtede skole Lincoln High - en skole fuld af ungdomskriminelle. Den hårdnakkede Peter skyr ingen midler for at beskytte sine eneområder. Bl.a. sælger han stoffer samt driver alfonsvirksomhed, og han sørger for at skolen lever i konstant frygt. Eftersom konflikten mellem lærere og elever intensiveres står det klart, at nogen bliver nødt til at lære en lektie, som de aldrig vil glemme. Lige så rå som "Krigerne" og ligeså voldsom som "Køterne". Dette er en af 80´ernes store film. Spilletid: 94 minutter Produktionsår: 1982

I can't see the problem with text. XML file has UTF-8 encoding tag. UTF-8 is set in Google Merchant Center. What is wrong here?

Comment: You say it has a UTF-8 encoding tag (presumably in the XML declaration), but is it actually in UTF-8? My guess is that it claims to be UTF-8 but isn't.

Comment: Ok, how to make it all UTF-8?

Comment: Check what options your favourite text editor provides.